# PyQt5 signals and slots in MVC model not working

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt5

\EDIT: simplified code to minimum.

I'm not able to connect button.clicked to the function in MVC approach. When debugging the code, all works fine for some time (2-5 clicks) and than no reaction to click. When I run the app in normal mode (no debug) no reaction to click at all. No Errors whatsoever.

I'm trying to follow example from here (MVC model): https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-gui-calculator/#creating-a-calculator-with-python-and-pyqt, which works fine. I tried some other examples from web, and also work fine, so seems problem with my code, and not the installation/configuration issue.

I'm completely clueless now and not even sure what to ask google...

Below the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(807, 567)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.btn_rand = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_rand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 170, 175, 34))
        self.btn_rand.setText("Random")


class GUIWords(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class GUIWordsCtr:
    def __init__(self, view):
        self._view = view
        self._connectSignals()

    def _connectSignals(self):
        self._view.btn_rand.clicked.connect(self._print)

    def _print(self):
        print("rand")

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
view = GUIWords()
view.show()
GUIWordsCtr(view)
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

When I merge classes GUIWords and GUIWordsCtr, all works as expected. So apparently the problem is that i do something wrong when passing class GUIWords to GUIWordsCtr. But it's exactly as in calc example mentioned above....

Lack of any error drives me crazy, and works when debuging but not in Run mode. Some kind of magic for me :(

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: here you can find words.py file and dic.s3db file to read from app: https://github.com/zielaskowski/words

Comment: /just edit: the name of file is words_minimal.py obviosly :)

Comment: no it's not an MRE, if it was an MRE then I would just have to make a copy-paste and then run the script but obviously I can't do it.

Comment: sorry, probably because i'm new to python, but i opened new project in pycharm, used system interpreter (not venv), copy/paste the code from github...and looks like MRE for me. What am I missing? (i provide dic.s3db file just in case command menu/openDB will work. not necessary to reproduce the problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(807, 567)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.btn_rand = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_rand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 170, 175, 34))
        self.btn_rand.setText("Random")


class GUIWords(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class GUIWordsCtr(QtCore.QObject):                     # + (QtCore.QObject)
    def __init__(self, view):
        super(GUIWordsCtr, self).__init__(view)        # +
    
        self._view = view
        self._connectSignals()

    def _connectSignals(self):
        self._view.btn_rand.clicked.connect(self._print)

    def _print(self):
        print("rand")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = GUIWords()
    view.show()

    GUIWordsCtr(view)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I was close to give up python...you saved me :) Don't know why yet, but it works. Need to read more about classes inheritance. And strange that calc example I linked seems dosen't inherit from QObject...and my solution worked in debug mode only....i see that a lot ahead of me. Thank you.

Comment: @michal  Take your time, comprehend, think about why something goes wrong. You can cope with everything, if not yourself, then with the help of others. Good luck to you.